# Does coffee taste different when it is ground at home?

Tags: ground-coffee

Is there a difference in the taste of the coffee that I grind myself versus the ground coffee that I buy from the store? Does the size of the ground change the taste of the coffee that I brew?

Comment: Welcome to Coffe SE. It is expected to ask one question for each title. As the answer to your first question is a clear no, you may focus to the second and consider editing your question if you wish. (If you ask about bean varieties, as many pre-ground coffee is mostly blend, you may search for them in the site.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I bypass the first question.*

Yes, ground size considerably affects the taste of the final cup. In general, there's a common rule of five component for a good cup of coffee. Each component must require its precedent.

1. Good beans
2. Good roasting
3. Homogenously/correct-sized grinding
4. Correct equipment
5. Skilled cook

(Italians mostly merge first two articles and name it as [4M for espresso](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/3168/whats-4ms-of-espresso).)

As stated above, the grounds must be all at the same size. Moreover they must be the correct size. The finest for Turkish, a bit less fine for espresso, boulders are good for French press, etc.

Answer (score 1):

> [Ground Coffee Beans: The Pros & Cons](https://www.theroasterie.com/blog/should-i-buy-ground-coffee-beans-or-whole-coffee-beans/)

Keep in mind that when you buy ground coffee you may be sacrificing a little flavor but you’re saving yourself valuable time (in the morning that can make all the difference in the world—we’re talking to you sleepyheads!). If you prefer the convenient route, we do have a few tips to get the most out of the grounds you buy:

Buy a week’s worth of grounds at a time to insure you’ll get the most flavors out of your ground beans.
    Store your grounds properly away from coffee killers. Our Roasterie   AirScape Container is like a coffee bodyguard.

> ```
> Whole Coffee Beans: Nothin’ But Pros
> ```

If you want to get the most flavorful coffee possible, recommend buying your beans whole. Grinding is a crucial, yet overlooked component of the brewing process. It’s not as simple as just grinding the beans in any old coffee grinder. An even grind is the perfect grind. If you don’t have a good grinder, you won’t extract enough flavor out of the beans. Blade grinders can’t provide an even grind so when hot water for brewing passes over the ground, it’s passing over an uneven surface area.

We recommend that if you decide to grind beans yourself, get a burr or mill grinder. These types of grinders grind the coffee in an even consistency. Uniform consistency is essential when it comes to extracting the most flavor out of your coffee beans.

When it comes to purchasing our beans, it doesn’t really matter whether you buy them whole or ground. We’ll make sure that no matter what way you choose to buy them, you’ll receive the best beans possible!

> PS: `ground size is important as well, all depends what you try to get from your cup of coffee:
>   1.grounding too **fine** can lead to have coffee beans part in our cup.
>
> 2.**fine ground** will lead to much more *caffeine* content(can say about the espresso type requirement), too fine can lead to higher compression in the espresso machine and can be dangerous.

All being said: **coffee** should be more than an awake call in the morning, should be **ART** and as much you research/try methods, starting from ground home and moving to home roast, you'll be amazed by the taste and types, flavors from all around the world. :)

[link to a blog about coffee](https://www.theroasterie.com/blog/should-i-buy-ground-coffee-beans-or-whole-coffee-beans/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  The coffee that you grind at home is more fresh.  Grinding coffee produces more surface area and dramatically accelerates the staling process. Fresh roasted beans are "fresh" for approximately two weeks (you find varying data|opinions on this).  Ground coffee is "fresh" for several hours (you will also find varying data|opinions on this, but it's generally much shorter).

Grind size (combined with immersion) time has a direct and noticeable impact on the final cup product.  Finer grinds (and longer immersion times) produce a different flavor profile than coarser grind and short immersion times.  Then there are cross over examples like espresso which gets a unique profile by using a fine grind and short extraction time (perhaps the shortest).  There are several questions on the site relating to how grind size, immersion time and temperature affect flavor profile.