# What are the 4M's of espresso?

Tags: espresso, flavor, espresso-machine, grinder, barista

"4M" is something that I have been heard of as a requirement set for tasty espresso.

What are these four important quality factors that affect the flavor of final espresso cup?

Comment: Working on the knowledge base of the site and getting a generic answer out? Well done!

Answer (score 12):

**4M** is a term mainly used among Italians for espresso. It is a placeholder for four words that start with "M" in Italian that affects espresso preparation. [Some information can be found here](http://www.brewed-coffee.com/coffee/the-4ms-of-espresso/).

These M's are:

- **Miscela**: The coffee-blend; it covers the selection and blending of the beans as well as proper roasting.
- **Macinazione**: The grinder; proper grinding of the given blend and its usage when its still fresh.
- **Macchina**: The espresso-machine; usage of the given grounds with a proper espresso-machine.
- **Mano**: Skill of the barista; usage of all above with skill.

Answer (score 3):

Some people add the fifth M, referring to "Maintenance" (keeping equipment clean, espresso machine descaled, having burrs in the grinder regularly replaced etc.)

Comment: Mostly, I count the (quality & blend of) beans and the roast as separate. But never thought of this. Nice point.