# What's the difference between Turkish and Italian coffee?

Tags: espresso, turkish-coffee

Is there any difference between Turkish coffee and Italian coffee?

Comment: I assume you need basic definitions. In the course of providing you some references I realized we have not got a proper espresso definition in the site. I will recommend two starting points as you can search for more under relevant tags. [Turkish](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/1833/what-gives-turkish-coffee-that-unique-quality) and [espresso](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/3168/what-are-the-4ms-of-espresso)

Comment: espresso is not coffee. it is mainly sugar with a coffee taste ;-)

Comment: @MaxMuster You’re going to the wrong places then. Espresso should have zero added sugar.

Comment: @MaxMuster Those products, like mochas and even lower-sugar drinks like lattes and cappuccinos, contain espresso. They are not espresso. Sort of like how a cake is not an egg.

Answer (score 7):

If you mean the products you see at a grocer, the answer is simply grind. "Turkish coffee" is a finer grind setting than espresso, so that the final product very closely resembles dust. "Italian coffee" is likely either espresso ground to be used with an espresso machine or literally "imported from Italy".

Turkish coffee is for use with a special, Turkish brewing process. The coffee dust is mixed with water in a special pot called a cezve or an ibrik. The solution is brought to a boil. Then the coffee is scooped or poured from the pot. Turkish coffee is drunk unfiltered, so you drink the actual coffee like you would with cocoa.

Espresso is brewed by forcing water through coffee grounds at pressure. The pressure extracts oils and compounds from the coffee to create the famous Italian coffee called espresso. The grounds have to be relatively course compared to Turkish to support this process; too fine grinds in an espresso machine would clog the machine. Espresso is partially filtered, meaning you don't drink most of the actual coffee grounds.